# Error Connecting to Personal Geodatabase: 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace'

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, arcmap

A Customer of mine has a Problem with my in vb.net developed extension in ArcMap. The extension is installed on a Windows 8.1 with ArcMap 10.3. First it worked fine, but now (since one week) there comes an error from the 'System.Transactions.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace' when the extension try to connect via oledb with an access db (personal geodatabase). The strange thing is, that the stand alone app (without ArcMap) has no problems to connect (and it uses the same oledb object). Does anyone have a clou what can cause the problem? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The problem was a brocken config-file (user.config) in the user-account (C:\Users\\AppData\Local\ESRI\DefaultDomain_Path_...\).